# Python: Regular Expressions

Tags: python

I'm trying to use regular expressions to search through all files in a directory then eventually it will change the name of the files.

Here's what I have so far.

```
def regExp():
    os.chdir("C:/Users/David/Desktop/Test/Files")
    files = os.listdir(".")
    for x in (files):
        inputFile = open((x), "r")
        content = inputFile.read()
        inputFile.close()
        try:
            regex_txt = ("\(;;\)")
            regex = re.compile(regex_txt)
            print (regex.findall(x))
```

Getting the following error message

```
File "<module1>", line 108
    print (regex.findall(x))
                           ^
```

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Could you show the code in its entirety, making sure the indentation appears exactly as it is in your source file.

Comment: Is this Python 3.x by chance? (Parenthesis around `print` are required in 3.x as it's now a function and not a special syntax construct.. try a search for `[python] [print] SyntaxError` on SO. If one of those questions/answers solve this issue, please delete this post.)

Comment: That `findall` is not going to be very useful. If `x` is, say, `'foo.txt'`, the result will be `['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']` (one `''` for each character in `x`, plus one extra). What are you actually _trying_ to do?

Comment: +1 to pst. You wouldn't get a `SyntaxError` for calling an unknown method or otherwise using the `regex` variable incorrectly. Even if you'd done something like `print regex..findall(x)`, the caret would point to the second dot. Since the caret is pointed at the end of the first token after `print`, it's almost certainly complaining about the `print`.

Comment: have updated the question with full code. Basically I am trying to search a cache and find files with certain strings

Comment: When I try to run the exact code in your updated question, I get a different error: `IndentationError: unexpected unindent` on the line after the `print (regex.findall(x))`. You also need to add a matching `except` statement after the `try:` somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you don't have an `except` or a `finally` block with your `try` block. A `try` block on its own is meaningless, and so Python insists that you have either

```
try:
    your code
except SomeException:
    handle it
```

or

```
try:
    your code
finally:
    clean up
```

Comment: if I put an except in wont it print the statement after for every file the regex doesnt appear in?

Comment: @LWH91 I'm not quite sure what you're asking. I can't see any exception the code you have in the `try` block is likely to raise, so would recommend simply removing the `try` keyword.

Comment: @LWH91: You can play with the `findall` function in the interactive interpreter to see when it raise an exception. If you call it on a string with no matches, it won't raise anything, it'll just return an empty list. The only way it will raise an exception is if you do something like call it on a number instead of a string (which raises a `TypeError`). If you want to handle that, you need a `try` _and_ an `except`. If you want to leave that as an error for the user to see, you want neither `try` nor `except`.

Comment: @LWH91: More importantly, why did you add the `try:`? You must have had some reason for it being there. If you tell us what you were hoping to do, we can tell you how to do it. Otherwise, all we can do is make random guesses, which may not make any sense to you.

Answer (score -3):

You should be using :

```
re.findAll(regex,text,flags)
```

If you want to pre compile it, I think you can do it like this:

```
 my_regex= re.compile(pattern)
 result = my_regex.match(string)
```

Comment: `match` is not the same thing as `findall`. The way to do the equivalent of `re.findall` with a precompiled regexp is `my_regex.findall`. Exactly as the OP wrote it.